# jQuery Fading an Element on top of a Fixed Positioned Element - iPad Only?

Tags: jquery, ipad, mobile-safari, positioning, fadein

I'm seeing clunky fades when fading between two elements that live on top of a fixed positioned background element. Changing the background to absolute positioning fixes this.

The odd thing is that this clunkiness is only for iOS, not on my desktop. It's as if the fade happens, then Mobile Safari wants to redraw the box again.

Has anyone else seen this?

My code is too exhaustive to post, so I'm broadly throwing this question out there.

Thanks!

** UPDATE **

Here's a fiddle that's similar to what I'm doing, but it doesn't reproduce the problem I'm seeing on iPad: http://jsfiddle.net/pyhxL/5/

Comment: A demonstration link or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful.

Comment: Original post updated...

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen it, so I can't give you any advice to the cause of this problem. However: if the fiddle does work and your code does not, then I would work backwards from the fiddle version up to your version to see where it starts breaking.